# Big query SQL Error: Column name user_dim is ambiguous at [3:3]

Tags: jquery, sql, google-bigquery, sql-query-store

how can i run a query that goes through both my android and iOS data to return what i need in one table.

currently getting the above error when i run this

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id,
  user_dim.device_info.device_category,
  user_dim.device_info.user_default_language,
  user_dim.device_info.platform_version,
  user_dim.device_info.device_model,
  user_dim.geo_info.country,
  user_dim.geo_info.city,
  user_dim.app_info.app_version, 
  user_dim.app_info.app_store,
  user_dim.app_info.app_platform
FROM
```

`app.com_aaa_IOS.app_events_20171204`,`app.com_aaa_ANDROID.app_events_20171204`

Comment: Do you want an `UNION ALL` of these two tables?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
  user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id,
  user_dim.device_info.device_category,
  user_dim.device_info.user_default_language,
  user_dim.device_info.platform_version,
  user_dim.device_info.device_model,
  user_dim.geo_info.country,
  user_dim.geo_info.city,
  user_dim.app_info.app_version, 
  user_dim.app_info.app_store,
  user_dim.app_info.app_platform
FROM
  app.com_aaa_IOS.app_events_20171204

UNION ALL

SELECT
  user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id,
  user_dim.device_info.device_category,
  user_dim.device_info.user_default_language,
  user_dim.device_info.platform_version,
  user_dim.device_info.device_model,
  user_dim.geo_info.country,
  user_dim.geo_info.city,
  user_dim.app_info.app_version, 
  user_dim.app_info.app_store,
  user_dim.app_info.app_platform
FROM
  app.com_aaa_ANDROID.app_events_20171204
```

Answer (score 1):

**Standard SQL**

You are using [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/), then you should to use UNION ALL operator:

```
SELECT
  user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id,
  ...
FROM app.com_aaa_IOS.app_events_20171204
UNION ALL
SELECT
  user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id,
  ...
FROM app.com_aaa_ANDROID.app_events_20171204`
```

Remember you can use [Wildcard Tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference):

```
SELECT
FROM
  `<project-id>.<dataset-id>.<table-prefix>*`
WHERE
  bool_expression
```

**Legacy SQL**

If you switch to [Legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql) then you can use comma separated tables as union, like in your query.

> Combinations of these data sources can be queried using the comma, which is the UNION ALL operator in BigQuery